# TFS 2012: Add the "effort" field to the "backlog" page

Tags: tfs

The default **"Backlog" page on TFS 2012** looks like the screenshot below.
I'd like to **add the "Effort" field to the "quick add" panel** on the top (see arrow).

I know it involves changing xml templates, but I can't figure out the specifics.
**How** would I go about accomplishing that? :)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the AgileProcessConfig of the project:

Export the config file:

```
witadmin exportagileprocessconfig /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:d:\temp\test\agileprocessconfig.xml
```

Edit the agileprocessconfig.xml by adding the Effort field:

```
<ProductBacklog>
 <AddPanel>
  <Fields>
    <Field refname="System.Title" />
    <Field refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
  </Fields>
</AddPanel>
```

Import  the file back to your project

```
witadmin importagileprocessconfig /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName /f:d:\temp\test\agileprocessconfig.xml
```

Comment: Hi. I've exactly tried this but the new field is not shown in the interface. Coukld anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you used the correct refname and did it exist in the WorkItemTypeDefinitions of WorkItems that are defined as Backlog items?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. In fact I used fields which are available in the "Columns" Section just below. I even added several new Fields. When I export the the definition the settings are correctly saved.